# How to define default image in wpf usercontrol library

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have created a wpf usercontrol library with my custom usercontrols to use them in different projects.

I have a button with an default image but I want the ability the change the button's image if needed:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BTN_SEARCH_IMAGE =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonImage", typeof (string), typeof (Searchbar));
```

My property wrapper:

```
   public string ButtonImage
    {
        get
        {
            var strToCheck = GetValue(BTN_SEARCH_IMAGE) as string;
            return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strToCheck)
                ? @"WPF_Controls;Component/Images/Search.png"
                : strToCheck;
        }
        set { SetValue(BTN_SEARCH_IMAGE, value); }
    }
```

In XAML:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="WPF_Controls.Searchbar"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 Name="SearchBar">
        <DockPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=SearchBar}">
        <Button Name="btnSearch"
                DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                Command="{Binding Path=SearchCommand}">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=ButtonImage}" />
        </Button>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

If the user doesn't bind anything to ButtonImage the default image should display otherwise the user's choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a `Style`. If you define that Style somewhere accessible to the whole application (e.g. App.xaml), it will automatically apply to all `SearchBar`s.

```
<Style TargetType="l:SearchBar">
    <Setter Property="ButtonImage" Value="TheImage" />
</Style>
```

The **Value** of the **Setter** can be a binding to a `StaticResource`, or however you defined the image. Normally you would do this in a `ResourceDictionary`, where you can define the default image as `StaticResource`.

If the `ButtonImage` is set locally on the image, it will override the value set by the Style. See [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Anchor_3) for reference on that.